# Setting anchor point for UIView layer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a UIView subclass that I want to be able to move around within it's superview. When the user touches the UIView somewhere outside `self.center` but within `self.bounds` it "jumps" because I add the new location to `self.center` to achieve the actual move. To avoid this behavior I'm trying to set an anchor point that lets the user grab and drag the view anywhere within it's bounds.

My problem is that when I calculate the new anchor point (as shown in the code below) nothing happens, the view doesn't change position at all. On the other hand, if I set the anchor point to a precalculated point I can move the view (but then of course it "jumps" to the precalculated point). How come this doesn't work as expected?

Thanks.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    // Only support single touches, anyObject retrieves only one touch
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint locationInView = [touch locationInView:self];

    // New location is somewhere within the superview
    CGPoint locationInSuperview = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

    // Set an anchorpoint that acts as starting point for the move
    // Doesn't work!
    self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / self.bounds.size.width, locationInView.y / self.bounds.size.height);
    // Does work!
    self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.01, 0.0181818);

    // Move to new location
    self.center = locationInSuperview;
}
```

Comment: make sure you have full understanding of anchorPoint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22188420/550393

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Kris Van Bael pointed out, your going to need to do the anchor point calculations in the `touchsBegan:withEvent:` method in order not to negate the movement.  Additionally, since changing the layer's `anchorPoint` will move the view's initial position, you have to add an offset to the view's `center` point to avoid a 'jump' after the first touch.

You can do this by calculating (and adding to your view's `center` point) the offset based on the difference between the initial and final anchorPoints (multiplied by your view's width/height) or you could set the view's `center` to the initial touch point.

Something like this perhaps:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint locationInView = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint locationInSuperview = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

    self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(locationInView.x / self.frame.size.width, locationInView.y / self.frame.size.height);
    self.center = locationInSuperview;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint locationInSuperview = [touch locationInView:self.superview];

    self.center = locationInSuperview;
}
```

More info on `anchorPoint`'s from apple's docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html) and a similar SO question I referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968017/changing-my-calayers-anchorpoint-moves-the-view).

Answer (score 0):

You should update the anchorpoint only on TouchBegin. If you recalculate it all the time (TouchMoved), it is logical that the subview doesn't move.

Comment: Thanks, of course you are right! Also, there is obviously no point in recalculating the anchor point since the user won't move the finger within the bounds when the actual move starts.
Changing the update of anchorPoint to touhesBegan did however arise an offset problem as Sam highlights in his answer.