# Scaling a UIView from a point other than the center, looking for alternatives to anchorPoint

Tags: ios, matrix, transform, calayer, scale

I've been using CGAffineTransformMakeScale to scale a UIView. This scales it by it's default anchorPoint, which is (.5, .5) -- the center. I'd like to scale it so that it stretches towards the left, as if it were zooming towards the left. I can accomplish this by setting the anchorPoint to the right center. However, this causes problems with setting the frame, etc. Is there a better way to apply a scale transform like I want. I was thinking I could do it with a custom transform matrix, but I am no good with matrix math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use anchorPoint, to get around the frame weirdness just store and reload it as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968017/changing-my-calayers-anchorpoint-moves-the-view/1968425#1968425).

Answer (score 1):

**First run this code and you will have better understanding. Here lblLabel is my label, you can change accordingly. Also check CGPoint(x: 10, y: 98) and CGPoint(x: 10, y: 108) as par > your requirements.
    This will animate from Top Left corner of label. Change anchor point and position as par your requirements.**

---

---

```
self.lblLabel.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0,y :0.0)
        self.lblLabel.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 98)
        lblLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
             self.lblLabel.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 108)
            self.lblLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
        }
```