# Moving UIView from bottom to top

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiview, uistoryboard

How can I move a view from bottom to top on my code:

```
colorView.hidden=NO;
colorView=[[UIView alloc]init];
colorView.frame=CGRectMake(0,480,320, 480);
colorView.bounds=CGRectMake(0,200,320, 280);
colorView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
colorView.alpha=1.0f;
[webView addSubview:colorView];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[self createTransparentView];
```

So how can I add the animation here?

Comment: What have you tried? Which research have you done prior to asking this question?

Comment: you could use CATransition on view layer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23195924/1378447

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Initially, add your view:

```
self.postStatusView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 460);
```

For the animation from bottom to top add below:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.1
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     self.postStatusView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
[self.view addSubview:self.postStatusView];
```

For removing the view

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                              delay:0.5
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
    self.postStatusView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 460);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             if (finished)
                                 [self.postStatusView removeFromSuperview];
                         }];
```

Comment: postStatus is ur view name ryt?

Comment: Should that be `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn` (emphasis on **Option**)?

Comment: Replaced `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn` by `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn` in XCODE 6.1. Then it worked.

Comment: does actually works? For me it doesn't nothing, just adds the view when completed at the right location.

Comment: How Can achieve it animating from Top to bottom... And my subview should be placed at x : 7 and y : 70. As well as for removing from bottom to top

Comment: @AbiramiBala just animate with X position value , above code deals with y position value

Answer (score 3):

```
self.colorView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 460);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 delay:0.1
                options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
             animations:^{
                 self.colorView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
             } 
             completion:^(BOOL finished){
             }];
[self.view addSubview:self.colorView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                          delay:0.5
                        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
self.colorView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 490, 320, 460);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [self.colorView removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
```

Comment: Rather than just throwing some code out, it would be much more useful to explain what is being done and why,

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 490, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

[UIView animateWithDuration:.35
                      delay:0.0
                    options:  UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1   delay:0.0
                      options:  UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut   animations:^{

                         self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width , [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1   delay:0.0
                          options:  UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

                              self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

                         } completion:^(BOOL finished){

                }];
        }];
 }];
```