# Layer Position jumps at start of (Core) Animation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation

So, I'm trying to create a tile flipping effect, like on Windows Phone 7.

So far I have the following code, but I have a couple of queries.

```
CALayer *layer = self.theRedSquare.layer;
CATransform3D initialTransform = self.theRedSquare.layer.transform;
initialTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -1000;

[UIView beginAnimations:@"Scale" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
layer.transform = initialTransform;
layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(-0.3, 0.5);

CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = self.theRedSquare.layer.transform;

rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, M_PI , 0 , -self.theRedSquare.bounds.size.height/2, 0);

layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

**1. How come my my red square (a simple UI view) translates to the right at the start of the animation?**

**2. For the anchor point is it possible to set a position on the parent view? At the moment I am arbitrarily setting it relative to the current view.**

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

*Before animation*

[image: Before]

*During animation (notice the square has shifted right)*

[image: During]

*After animation (notice the square has shifted right)*

[image: After]

Video added: [example video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8i0Bdmluh4&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: This helped me: https://medium.com/@filippotosetto/animate-cashapelayer-6fa54adb22eb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-(void)setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint forView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x, view.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y);
    CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * view.layer.anchorPoint.x, view.bounds.size.height * view.layer.anchorPoint.y);

    newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(newPoint, view.transform);
    oldPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(oldPoint, view.transform);

    CGPoint position = view.layer.position;

    position.x -= oldPoint.x;
    position.x += newPoint.x;

    position.y -= oldPoint.y;
    position.y += newPoint.y;

    view.layer.position = position;
    view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
}

-(void)animateView:(UIView *)theRedSquare
{
    CALayer *layer = theRedSquare.layer;
    CATransform3D initialTransform = theRedSquare.layer.transform;
    initialTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -1000;

    [self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(-0.3, 0.5) forView:theRedSquare];


    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Scale" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    layer.transform = initialTransform;


    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = theRedSquare.layer.transform;

    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, M_PI , 0 , -theRedSquare.bounds.size.height/2, 0);

    layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;

    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Taken from This, and slightly tweaked.. Hopefully it helps
[Changing my CALayer's anchorPoint moves the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968017/changing-my-calayers-anchorpoint-moves-the-view)

Comment: How do you get the animation to just animate in? (That Flip in) I've been trying for hours to figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

If you make the square its own view, flipping is built-in

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.35f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
     forView:self.window cache:YES];

// change to the new view (make this one hidden, the other not)

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I appreciate it wasn't overly obvious from my description, but I'm not after flipping from the spot. I want to flip around the left hand edge of my red square (which is already a UIView). See the following video fro the kind of effect I am after : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgoGDPF_NGo

Answer (score 2):

The acceptable range of the `anchorPoint` of a `CALayer` is [0,1]. In your case, where you are attempting to flip around the Y axis, your layer's anchor point should be [0, 0.5].

Comment: I had this working fine, but the red UIView shifts right before even starting the animation. I'll try and get a video. Interestingly -0.3 for the anchorPoint works, it rotates around the y-axis offset to the left.

Comment: have added a video to show the problem. on the first run of the animation the square shifts right a number of pixels. can't seem to work it out.