# iOS -- How to scale the UIView with left top point?

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform

I want to fix a point (left top point) and scale (zoom out) the UIView according to the point

like this image

[image]

Now I use `self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( 0.7 , 0.7);` to scale the UIView , But it only can scale the UIView according to the center point
[image]

Edit

I try to use set anchorPoint with (0,0) but the view position be wrong

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the `anchorPoint`?

Comment: view.layer.anchorPoint, set it to 0,0

Comment: @luk2302 I have update my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468233/why-does-my-view-jump-when-setting-the-layer-anchorpoint-in-an-animation-block

Comment: You need a little more than changing the anchor point: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-change-a-views-anchor-point-without-moving-it

Answer (score 4):

Use anchorPoint property:

```
self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

Comment: You can use CGPointZero (the same as 0,0)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set anchorPoint of layer
`container!.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)`