# Correct Image and Font Scale on different Devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, autolayout

I have a simple view with a text and an Image. I ran this app on iPhone6Plus and iPhone5. Then I made a screenshot of both and enlarged the iPhone5 screenshot such that it matches the size of the screenshot from iPhone6Plus. Here is the result:

[image]

As you can se the size of the text the size of the image and there positions are not identical but they should be to look the same on different screen sized.

Here is an example of a [weather app](https://github.com/JakeLin/SwiftWeather) running on different screens:

[image]

As you can see the sizes and the positions of text and image are identical.

The image is loaded from asset catalog:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "shower3")
self.view.addSubView(imageView)
imageView.center = self.view.center
```

I have only created a 128x128 image and put it into the @1x version in the asset cataloge.

Let me rephrase this. I run the wether app on iPhone5 make ascreenshot and iPhone6 make a screenshot. Then I resize both screenshots to the same size. Then I see that both fontsize as well as images dimension are exactly equal on both screenshots. This means that on each device font and image must have different dimensions. How can I do that?

**How can I achieve that text and image have identical proportions on different screen sizes? How does the [Weather App](https://github.com/JakeLin/SwiftWeather) do it?**

Comment: have you created a @3x version of your image?

Comment: No I only have the @1x version. As in the weather app: https://github.com/JakeLin/SwiftWeather

Comment: Please post the code you are using, or list the constraints you have.

Answer (score 12):

**Images**

I am the creator and one of the developers of the [Swift Weather app](https://github.com/JakeLin/SwiftWeather). The app doesn't use three versions of images because I didn't make those images and it was a Pull Request from another developer. I don't have the origin images.

As [@Daniil Korotin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4320719/daniil-korotin) mentioned, iOS uses `points` to calculate image and font sizes. iOS uses `let screenScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` to retrieve the screen scale and pick up the proper size (1x, 2x or 3x) of the image. If we don't provide the proper size of the image, for example, in SwiftWeather app, we have only 1x version of the image (as the screenshot below), iOS will upscale the image to render on retina devices. On iPhone 6 Plus, it actually does downsampling for 3x assets. Please have a look at [iPhone 6 Screens Demystified](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified). In some case, if you don't provide 2x or 3x images, on retina devices, the image upscaled from 1x may looks blurry. We should always provide 1x, 2x and 3x images if possible. 
[image]

**Fonts**

iOS renders fonts according to the specified `points`. It will automatically convert the points to certain pixel based on the devices' screen scale (as mentioned above).
[image]

**How can I achieve that text and image have identical proportions on different screen sizes? How does the Weather App do it?**
**The answer is Auto Layout**

You can see we set constraints for the image view (used for the weather icon) as below.
[image]
The width and height are always 150 `points`, please notice it is `points` nor `pixels`. It will render the same size (for look and feel, not for exactly pixels) for different devices. For your first image (iPhone 6 Plus vs. iPhone 5), it looks different because maybe your simulators have different scale. A better way to check how auto layout elements lay on the screen is to use Preview in Interface Builder.

[image]

Open the main storyboard, and click on Assistant Editor. On the right hand side, select Preview (on the top left). And click the plus sign ( on the bottom left) to add different devices. You can see they are identical proportions on different screen sizes.

If you have any questions, please let me know.

**Something maybe off topic**

If I design the images/assets, I would like to use some vector base tool like Sketch to design the assets and export them to three different sizes. Please have a look my another project [iOSAnimationSample](https://github.com/JakeLin/iOSAnimationSample). It has a Sketch file for the design.

[image: Sketch design]
Sketch design

[image: Export assets to different sizes]
Export assets to different sizes

In that case, iOS can pick up the proper assets for different devices.

Comment: Let me rephrase this. I run the wether app on iPhone5 make ascreenshot and iPhone6 make a screenshot. Then I resize both screenshots to the same size. Then I see that both fontsize as well as images dimension are exactly equal on both screenshots. This means that on each device font and image must have different dimensions. How can I do that?

Comment: they do not have different dimensions. On Iphone5 one point maps to 2 pixels and on iphone6 one point maps to 3 pixels. So thats why they have same dimensions in terms of points. IOS deals with points not the pixels.

Comment: @stephan1001as M Abdul Sami said, They have same points. And render to different pixels. For fonts, it is vector base, it is not pixel relative. For image, it is automatically pick up the proper image (1x, 2x or 3x) or upscale the 1x to fit. Please let me know which part you feel unclear, I can update the answer.

Comment: @stephan1001Could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019170/what-is-pixel-and-points-in-iphone I may still don't get what your confusion is.

Answer (score 11):

The app you are referring to does not correctly support multiple screen sizes. The interface is scaled up to run on the 6 and 6 plus, which is why everything appears the same size.

Look at the screenshots from your app - the status bar is much smaller on the 6 plus. This is because it is *supposed* to take up less room on the screen. It's 20 points high on all devices.

Now look at the screenshot from the weather app - the status bars are the same size. Because the weather app does not support multiple screen sizes, iOS simply takes the smaller interface and scales it up to fill the screen.

If you want to achieve the same effect (which you shouldn't) then remove the `LaunchScreen.xib` file and use a launch image instead. But people don't buy larger phoned screens because they want to have the same content, but bigger. That would be achieved more cheaply by simply holding the phone closer to one's face.

You're supposed to take advantage of larger displays by allowing more content to be shown at once on the screen - more rows of data in a table, more text from a book, more images from a photo library.

In the case of a weather app the extra space should be used to display more rows of an hourly forecast or something, not just a larger version of a fairly useless icon depicting the type of weather.

I suspect it is only game support that means supporting larger screens properly is not already a requirement for app store submission. Supporting the 4 inch screen became mandatory quite quickly, you should expect a similar rule to be introduced for the 6 and 6 plus before too long.

If you want a specific element to always take up 50% of the width of the screen, or a label to always be the same size as an image, then you use autolayout constraints with *multipliers*. An autolayout constraint is of the basic structure:

```
attribute of A = (attribute of B * multiplier) + constant
```

Most of the time the multiplier is left as one, so you're just saying that this is 20 points to the left of that, or whatever, but you can use the multiplier as well, and say that A is the width of B, multiplied by 2 or 0.5 or whatever you like.

Comment: But how can I achieve  that the proportions are equal independent of the screen size?

Comment: You can add constraints with multipliers between different views (so A is twice the width of B or whatever)

Comment: This equation is incorrect. It's actually: `attribute of A = multiplier * attribute of B + constant`. see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html

Comment: @Tricky gosh, all these years and you're the first to notice! Thank you, I will edit

Answer (score 8):

iOS uses `points` to calculate image and font sizes. On non-retina screen 1 point equals 1 pixel, on retina screens — 2 pixels, and for iPhone 6 Plus it is equal to 3 pixels (some downscaling is applied, though). If you want to scale the image and font based on the actual **pixel** size of the screen, you can get the number of pixel per point like this:

```
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

The iPhone 5, 6 and 6 Plus screen aspect ratios are the same, while resolutions differ. If you want to simply keep proportions, then you have to pick a 'base' screen width or height (say, the iPhone 5 screen width, which is 320.0 points) and then calculate the proportion by dividing the actual device screen width (say, iPhone 6 Plus screen width, which is 414.0 points) by that 'base' width (414.0 / 320.0 = 1.29375). You can get the screen size like this:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Dividing `screenBounds`'s width by base width gives you the proportion. Then you just multiply all the sizes and margins with that proportion (1.29375 in our case for iPhone 6 Plus). Hope you get the idea.

P.S. A good guide to resolutions is [here](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified).

P.P.S. And in your case, as skorolkov mentioned below, the app just upscales everything for bigger screens (add/remove splash screens to enable/disable this upscaling).

**UPD:** Ok, now I see what confuses you. Here's the thing: when Apple initially released iPhone 6 and 6 Plus many apps didn't support their larger screens and bigger resolutions. So they decided that if an app lacks splash screens **specifically** made for those phones, it should use the **iPhone 5** resolution.

That's why you get the exact same pictures after manually resizing screenshots: the system does that too. It simply takes iPhone 5 'picture' and stretches it so that it fits larger screens. The drawback is clear (and visible, especially on iPhone 6 Plus): the fonts and images are blurry and upscaled (system interface elements, like status bar, get upscaled too). So basically you get the **iPhone 5 picture on all larger-screened devices** (you can check that by taking a screenshot on an iPhone 5, resizing it manually to fit iPhone 6/6 Plus resolution and comparing the actual iPhone 6/6 Plus screenshot to it).

To be clear: that's the behavior you currently get, but it's not good. To keep everything properly scaled using the devices' native resolution, use the method I described above (manual multiplication) or autolayouts with `equal height`/`width` set to desired ratios for interface elements.

Comment: It is done with proper storyboard settings. If you don't get it, you need to read some books/tutorials about autolayouts and Interface Builder in general.

Comment: Could you please explain what this app did as storyboard setting? How can I achieve the same when using InterfaceBuilder?

Comment: You can start here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: I still know how AutoLayout works but I do not get how the fonts and the images in the Weather App are resized on different screens.

Answer (score 4):

Weather App is using upscale mode to run on iPhone 6+. You can enable it by removing launch screens for 6/6+.

Go to asset catalog, select your launch image and unset 'iOS 8 or Later' checkbox in Attributes Inspector.

[Screenshot - your app has this set](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23696295/launch-image-screenshot-xcode.png)

[Screenshot from WeatherApp](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23696295/launch-image-screenshot-xcode-weather.png)

Answer (score 4):

in programatically (X and Y) we  pre define the values in constant  :

```
#define XScale [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 320.0f
#define YScale [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height / 568.0f
```

Then create UIImageView programatically

```
var imageView : UIImageView
imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(XScale *someValue, YScale * someValue, XScale *someValue, YScale *someValue));
imageView.image = UIImage(named:"image.jpg")
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

based on your screen size we need to set Constant values. We use for  iPhone5 and 4s screen.

Comment: Let me rephrase this. I run the wether app on iPhone5 make ascreenshot and iPhone6 make a screenshot. Then I resize both screenshots to the same size. Then I see that both fontsize as well as images dimension are exactly equal on both screenshots. This means that on each device font and image must have different dimensions. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi @stephan1001 Dimensions it differ  from devices.  so the way we can specify Auto layout or programatically we need to define it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set Layout constraint to all the views to make them look at same places and sizes in all screens sizes provided that the aspect ratio of screens are same.

Comment: Please post an example how to make this!

Comment: Did you even read the questions. The question is how to make identical proportions of images and fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to remove `autoResizing`functionality from view?
Click on inner arrow to remove `autoResize` view as per superview

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1. First turn off auto layout, auto resizing and size classes in storyboard.
2. Click on Images.xcassets icon and select all your graphics. In attribute inspector set Devices property to "Device Specific" and set the checkbox checked against "iPhone" and "Retina 4-inch"
3. Place all your graphics in 2x image set. You may place a higher resolution image set for better results with iPhone 6/6+.
4. Design your view for a reference device say iPhone 5 (320x568 portrait).
5. In your viewDidLoad method paste the following code

`self.view.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity,self.view.frame.size.width/320, self.view.frame.size.height/568);`

And you will have same result on iPhone 5/5s, iPhone 6/6+.

Comment: Let me rephrase this. I run the wether app on iPhone5 make ascreenshot and iPhone6 make a screenshot. Then I resize both screenshots to the same size. Then I see that both fontsize as well as images dimension are exactly equal on both screenshots. This means that on each device font and image must have different dimensions. How can I do that?