# hide TextFields Programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I have list of `UITextFields` with dropdown menu based on the option after `UILabel` need to show.

```
UITextField
DropdownMenu
UITextField
UITextField
```

Like above mentioned its showing starting application. after changing the dropdown menu need to show label.

```
UITextField
DropdownMenu
UILabel
UITextField
UITextField
```

I know how to hide the `UILabel` by using `label.hidden = true`. But after hiding, `UILabel` still occupies the space. After that only its showing that two `UITextField`. If any way to dynamically change position after hide the label.

I have used programmatically for creating the TextFields and Labels:

```
let textField1 = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.width - 40, height:45))
let textField2 = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: textField1.frame.origin.y + textField1.frame.size.height + 10, width: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.width - 40, height: 45))
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: textField2.frame.origin.y + textField2.frame.size.height + 10, width: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.width - 40, height: 45))
let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: button.frame.origin.y + button.frame.size.height + 10, width: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.width - 40, height: 45))
let textField3 = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: label1.frame.origin.y + label1.frame.size.height + 10, width: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.width - 40, height: 45))
let textField4 = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: textField3.frame.origin.y + textField3.frame.size.height + 10, width: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.width - 40, height: 45))
```

Comment: are you using autolayout or autoresizing

Comment: Using autolayout only @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Using autolayout programmatically or in storyboard? Can you paste your code here?

Comment: use a `UIStackView`

Comment: @vara i guess you need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904573/dynamically-moving-animating-a-uitextfield

Comment: can any one help with sample code??

Comment: in objective c we using table view for doing this type of thing, we keep one array with type(text field, lbl etc). And make one cell for every type. When we have to remove one item we just remove it from array and reload the table, no need to calculate the frame before/after adding new control and before/after removing control.

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements it looks like you are in need of using `UIStackView` control to fix this problem:

> so after hide but that place has empty

UIStackView adjust itself if one or more of the child controls adds/removes, depending on your parameters you set to UIStackView. Have a look at these links on how to use it:

[iOS 9: Getting Started with UIStackView](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-getting-started-with-uistackview--cms-24193)

[UIStackView Tutorial: Introducing Stack Views](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views)

Answer (score 0):

> @NeverHopeless is right, `UIStackView` is the perfect solution, here's
>   how you can use it programmatically:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let subviewArray = [TextFields1, TextFields2, Button, Label1, TextFields3, TextFields4]
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: subviewArray)
    stackView.axis = .Vertical  // It can also align horizontally
    stackView.distribution = .FillEqually  // You can try other options
    stackView.alignment = .Fill  // You can try other options
    stackView.spacing = 5  // Bigger spacing means larger distance between subviews
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(stackView)

}
```

For more about adding `UIStackView` programmatically , you can read about here: https://makeapppie.com/2015/11/11/how-to-add-stack-views-programmatically-and-almost-avoid-autolayout/

Answer (score 0):

StackView is a very good way to solve your problem.

But if you don't want to change your code much. You can change the height of your label = 0

```
label1.frame.size = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
```

But I still recommend to use stackView because it's more dynamical