# UIScreen mainScreen bounds returns iPad 2's bounds on iPad Air 2

Tags: ios, ipad

I've just restarted work on a project I last worked on 4 years ago. Back then, I was using Xcode 3.2 and an iPad 2. Now I am on Xcode 8.1 and an iPad Air 2.

I can build and run the project just fine with Xcode 8.1 but there is something strange going on when getting the screen size using

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

It returns 768x1024 pixels on my iPad Air 2 which can't be true because the iPad Air 2's native resolution is 1536x2048. 768x1024 is the resolution of the iPad 2, my old device.

Furthermore, not only does `bounds` return the wrong dimensions, I can also clearly see that the graphics I draw to my view have been upscaled.

So my assumption is that my project is running in some sort of legacy/compatibility mode that tries to make the app believe it is still running on an iPad 2 in a resolution of 768x1024 instead of a resolution twice as big. Could that be the case or what is the explanation for this phenomenon?

So how can I get this to work correctly? i.e. how can I get `bounds` to return 1536x2048 and stop automatic upscaling? I have already looked through the various options in Xcode but I don't see anything that could explain the behaviour I'm seeing here. My deployment target is set to iOS 10.1 so I don't really see why my app is put in this strange legacy mode or whatever it is...

Comment: *"It returns 768x1024 pixels"* - No, it returns 768x1024 **points**. Please read the documentation for the `UIScreen bounds` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused here you are getting correct bounds from here

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

`1536x2048` is the resolution of iPad Air 2 not its screen size i.e. iPad Air 2 is supporting @2x resolution.

If you will check bounds of iPad Air 2 then you will get `768x1024`

Comment: It's a common confusion of pixels vs points. Here's another stackoverflow link that covers this in more detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019170/what-is-pixel-and-points-in-iphone