# Why is the point unit in CSS equal to 1.333 pixels?

Tags: android, html, ios, css

There is much confusion in my organization around how many pixels are in a point and I have gone down a deep rabbit hole and I still do not have an answer to some questions which I am posting here...

First off, there are obvious differences between "physical pixels/device pixels" and CSS Pixels. As are there differences between "physical points" and point units on iOS.

This is a survey of what I have discovered:

**on iOS**
[What is pixel and points in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019170/what-is-pixel-and-points-in-iphone)

- 1 iOS point is equal to 1 physical pixel on a 1x device.
- iOS points are used as an abstract unit for density independent pixels in which 1 iOS point is equal to 1 density independent pixel.

**Android**
[What is the difference between "px", "dip", "dp" and "sp"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp)

- 1 android point does not equal 1 physical pixel on a 1x device.
- 1 android point equals 1/72 of an inch.
- 1 dp is used as a density independent pixel.

**Web**
https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

- 1 CSS point does not equal 1 physical pixel on a 1x device.
- Obviously CSS points are listed units are NOT RECOMMENDED.

**Sketch**

- According to Sketch units are by default in points and 1 point is
  equal to 1 pixel.

**InVision**

- 1 point is equal to 1 pixel.

I have also come across this formula:

```
pixel   = point * resolution (in terms of dpi) / 72
```

In which obviously the number of physical pixels in a point is variable...

**So, my question is**:

- Why is 1 CSS point equal to 1.333 CSS pixels?

Comment: The answer is, because it was decided thusly. I don't think there is any more logical reason.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't agree that this question is a duplicate of that question all the answers in that question are covered before I ask my actual question which is not answered in the previous question.

Comment: @mr-lister I don't agree that this question is a duplicate of that question all the answers in that question are covered before I ask my actual question which is not answered in the previous question.

Comment: I can't think of anything to say (in an answer) that hasn't been said in the answers in the linked questions already. A point is 1/72 inch and a pixel is 1/96 inch. You can keep repeating "yes, but why", but that won't gain you more insight. "That's how it was decided" is the best you can get.