# set a UIImageView anchorPoint without changing the location in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, layer

In order to make an image appear from left to right, I am setting the anchorPoint like so:

```
myImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
```

then animating it:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The animation works great, but by changing the image's anchorPoint, the image does not appear in the location where it was set in Interface Builder, it gets moved around quite a bit when that anchorPoint is set.

Does anybody know if there is a way to set the anchorPoint or accomplish this effect without changing the image's location in Interface Builder?

Thanks!

Comment: make sure you understand what is anchorPoint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22188420/550393

Answer (score 0):

In ViewDidLoad: Just Initialise Your ImageView Frame:

[ImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(900, 0, 69, 39)];

and write this below code:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                          delay:0.1 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                     animations:^{
                         //animation code
                         ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 345);

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         //completion code

                     }];
```

Comment: Please set Your frame according to your animation from where it has to come.(means you need to get from left.. so set the frame according to it in animateWithDuration:)

Comment: i had temporarily set the frame. Ignore the frame.