# Set layer.transform with CATransform3DRotate like UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight

Tags: ios, transformation, catransform3d

I've set up a view such that when the app navigates forward, it performs `transitionFromView` using the `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight` option. That yields an effect like:

[image: Using UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight]

Navigating backwards uses `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft`, but otherwise is the same. Ok, so far, so good.

Now, I've also set up a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` so that I can link the flipping of views with a user's horizontal gesture on the screen. But clearly I can't use `transitionFromView` in that case, so my gesture recognizer is manually setting the `transform` property of the `layer` with:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -800.0;
viewToTransform.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, M_PI * rotationPercent, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

But this is yielding a subtly different effect:

[image: CATransform3DRotate]

In the `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight` option of `transitionFromView` the view is scaled during the flipping animation such that the tallest edge of the flipped view stays the height of the container view. But when manually doing the `transform` of the `layer`, it's the center of the view that stays a constant size, slightly cropping the corners of the longer edge of the flipped view during the animation.

How do I achieve this effect when setting the `transform` property of the `layer` in my gesture recognizer (I probably want to adjust my `opacity`, too, to get the slight dimming effect that the `transitionFromView` achieves). I'm thinking I could use `CATransform3DMakeScale` and manually calculate the scaling function based upon the angle of the rotation and my particular `m34` setting, but before I go through that exercise, I want to make sure I'm not overlooking some more intuitive or natural way to achieve this simultaneous scaling and rotating that the standard flip animation entails. And even if I have to calculate the scaling factor manually, I'd appreciate guidance as to how to define that as a function of the `m34` setting and the angle (I'm no expert in the subtleties of vector transformations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transforms are all based around your layers anchorPoint.  That is the "pivot point" around which you rotate.

The anchorPoint uses a scale from 0 to 1 in both x and y and defaults to 0.5, 0.5

I believe you would want your anchor for your layer set like this:

```
viewToTransform.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);
```

There is some good info and research locations in the answers to this question:

[Changing my CALayer's anchorPoint moves the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968017/changing-my-calayers-anchorpoint-moves-the-view)

Comment: Yeah, I can move the anchor point to solve the scaling issue of the flip animation (I think I have to move `x`, though, not `y`; thus for the first half of a flip right-to-left animation, setting the `anchorPoint` to `1.0, 0.5` leaves the view properly scaled), but then the flipping view is no longer in the center, meaning that I have to calculate the `position` to move it to in order to keep it center aligned. I've just replaced the scaling problem with a position problem. I like your idea, but I'm not sure it quite solves the problem.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  You will probably need to use a complex two stage animation that rotates the page to a 90 degree point, but also translates it back into the screen half the width of the page, so that its in the middle of the screen and extends exactly top to bottom, then finishes the rotation and translates it back into the original position.

Comment: Agreed. I'm already doing two stage animation anyway (because the first half is animating the "current" view, and the second half is animating the "next" view), so doing a translate in that process probably will work and is probably easier than doing what I first imagined, marrying the rotate about `0.5, 0.5` with a scaling adjustment. +1

Answer (score 2):

HalR is correct, that to achieve the desired effect, one should change the `anchorPoint`. So for a horizontal flip rotating about the right edge of the view, one would set the anchor point as follows:

```
viewToTransform.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0.5);
```

But, that will shift the view, too, so one needs to combine the new `anchorPoint` with `CATransform3D` values that translates the view back to where it originally was. For example, here is a Swift 3 custom transition "animation controller" that does a horizontal flip animation.

```
class HorizontalFlipAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    enum TransitionType {
        case presenting
        case dismissing
    }

    let transitionType: TransitionType

    init(transitionType: TransitionType) {
        self.transitionType = transitionType

        super.init()
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let inView   = transitionContext.containerView
        let toView   = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to)!
        let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from)!

        var frame = inView.bounds

        func flipTransform(angle: CGFloat, offset: CGFloat = 0) -> CATransform3D {
            var transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(offset, 0, 0)
            transform.m34 = -1.0 / 1600
            transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, angle, 0, 1, 0)
            return transform
        }

        toView.frame = inView.bounds
        toView.alpha = 0

        let transformFromStart:  CATransform3D
        let transformFromEnd:    CATransform3D
        let transformFromMiddle: CATransform3D
        let transformToStart:    CATransform3D
        let transformToMiddle:   CATransform3D
        let transformToEnd:      CATransform3D

        switch transitionType {
        case .presenting:
            transformFromStart  = flipTransform(angle: 0,        offset: inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
            transformFromEnd    = flipTransform(angle: -.pi,     offset: inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
            transformFromMiddle = flipTransform(angle: -.pi / 2)
            transformToStart    = flipTransform(angle: .pi,      offset: -inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
            transformToMiddle   = flipTransform(angle: .pi / 2)
            transformToEnd      = flipTransform(angle: 0,        offset: -inView.bounds.size.width / 2)

            toView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
            fromView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)

        case .dismissing:
            transformFromStart  = flipTransform(angle: 0,        offset: -inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
            transformFromEnd    = flipTransform(angle: .pi,      offset: -inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
            transformFromMiddle = flipTransform(angle: .pi / 2)
            transformToStart    = flipTransform(angle: -.pi,     offset: inView.bounds.size.width / 2)
            transformToMiddle   = flipTransform(angle: -.pi / 2)
            transformToEnd      = flipTransform(angle: 0,        offset: inView.bounds.size.width / 2)

            toView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
            fromView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
        }

        toView.layer.transform = transformToStart
        fromView.layer.transform = transformFromStart
        inView.addSubview(toView)

        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.0) {
                toView.alpha = 0
                fromView.alpha = 1
            }
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                toView.layer.transform = transformToMiddle
                fromView.layer.transform = transformFromMiddle
            }
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.0) {
                toView.alpha = 1
                fromView.alpha = 0
            }
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5) {
                toView.layer.transform = transformToEnd
                fromView.layer.transform = transformFromEnd
            }
        }, completion: { finished in
            toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
            fromView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
            toView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            fromView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        })
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1.0
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image: Example flip]