# Rotating UIView after changing its AnchorPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, anchorpoint

I have a media player in my app that persists across view controllers, and trying to let the user dismiss it as depicted in following picture:

[image]

I've added a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to my player. When pan state changes I can calculate θ as below:

`θ = Arctan(opposite/adjacent)`

where adjacent is `anchorPoint.x - initialTouchLocation.x`, and opposite is `translation.y`

In my `UIPanGestureRecognizer`'s  `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, I'm snapshotting player, setting snapshot's frame as the actual player's frame, adding that to the super view. Then I'm changing the snapshot's anchor point based on what's recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5666430/609130)

And in `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` , I'm just calculating θ and rotating the snapshot accordingly.

here is the what I've got in `UIPanGestureRecognizer` action:

```
- (void)playerMovedDown:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.playerView];

    CCPlayer *playerView = (CCPlayer *) recognizer.view;
    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
            _adjacent = self.playerAnchorPoint.x - translation.x;


            self.playerSnapshot = [playerView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
            [playerView.superview addSubview:self.playerSnapshot];
            self.playerSnapshot.frame = playerView.frame;

            [playerView.superview sendSubviewToBack:playerView];
            [playerView.superview bringSubviewToFront:self.playerSnapshot];


            [self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(self.playerOriginalFrame.size.width * relativePlayerAnchorPoint,
                0) forView:playerView];
        }

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged : {
            _opposite = translation.y;
            CGFloat angel = atan2f(_opposite, _adjacent);
            self.playerSnapshot.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (-angel);
            NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.playerSnapshot.frame));
        }
        default: {

        }
    }
}
```

But once I'm trying to pan the player, the snapshot which should rotate on behalf of the actual view disappears.

I try finding player snapshot in [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) , apparently it's added to the view hierarchy but I can't find it anywhere in the screen.

Just wondering if anyone can help me with fixing this, or pointing something out there about this issue.

**Edit:**
I put `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.playerSnapshot.frame));`  in my `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` after I'm applying rotate transform, and observed something that I cannot explain

```
{{7602.2540144175437, 34747.255839671474}, {353.40894445994036, 270.70438804942387}}
{{7677.5559653403761, 34908.541487295603}, {353.41127718399275, 271.19899878758588}}
{{7764.1261318069446, 35092.834523913771}, {353.41188643557598, 271.76320186068915}}
{{7801.1330694789358, 35171.252487591031}, {353.41147875381648, 272.00296155658725}}
{{7844.4014697306702, 35262.665288048178}, {353.41049980147181, 272.28221631572524}}
```

The origin of the player snapshot is moved way off the screen! But still I don't know why that's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured that out, I was setting the anchorPoint incorrectly. I should have set that as a relative point like:

```
[self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(relativePlayerAnchorPoint, 0) forView:playerView];
```

and `relativePlayerAnchorPoint = 0.8f`